# Trig function phase shift

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I've come across a problem and I'm not successful in finding a definition of phase shift that would address my question. Is the phase shift of $-\cos (x + \frac{\pi}{2})$ equal to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ or $0$ since $-\cos (x + \frac{\pi}{2}) = \sin(x)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cosine is its own trig function; it's separate from sine (but closely related). So, while it's true that $−cos(x+\frac{\pi}{2})=sin(x)$, the phase shift is still $\frac{\pi}{2}$, because we're working with cosine. If we were working with sine, the phase shift would be $0$.

Hope that helps, and good luck!

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. I thought that but I wasn't sure. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$\sin x=-\cos\left(\frac\pi2+x\right)=\cos\left(\pi+\frac\pi2+x\right)$$

as $\displaystyle\cos(\pi+y)=-\cos y$

Comment: I understand that I can rewrite the function as some other function but I don't understand what does phase shift mean in this context.

Comment: @VojtechHauser, I think in $\cos(x+\alpha), \alpha$ should be phase shift

Comment: So in the case I described in my question do I have to rewrite the function $\sin(x)$ before "calculating" the phase shift? $-\cos(x)$ shifted by $\frac{\pi}{2}$ to the left is $\sin(x)$ shifted by $0$. It sounds to me that the first interpretation is somewhat more correct since it is in the terms of the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

The phase shift of $\operatorname{trigfunction}(ax + b)$ is the value of $x$ that solves $ax + b = 0$.

Put in a slightly different way, it's the value of $x$ that makes $\operatorname{trigfunction}(ax + b)$ equal to $\operatorname{trigfunction}(0)$.